# question about commiting tests for react native on GIT

Tags: git, react-native, testing, jestjs

I have some tests that pass on my local machine.
Now I want to "commit" the tests to GIT so I can have the CI/CD running the tests first.

My question is I cannot commit the test files to GIT.

There is nothing on

> .gitignore

to ignore the tests...

Why are they not being committed to the repo?

```
modified:   src/Components/Checkbox/Text/__tests__/Text.js
modified:   src/Components/Checkbox/Text/__tests__/__snapshots__/Text.js.snap
modified:   src/Components/Checkbox/__tests__/CheckBox.js
```

I do

> $git add .
>
> $git commit -m "tests"
>
> $git push

But the tests are not committed...

Comment: did you stage the changes, make a commit and push?

Comment: @azium yes I do, but the files are not committed, as mentioned in edited question, thanks

Comment: what happens if you change the folder name from `__tests__` to something else? I mean this is baseline git stuff we're talking about.. there's nothing magic or specific about react native that prevents you from pushing or adding files to your git tree

Comment: perhaps something in `~/.gitignore_global`?